# Export HTML DataTable in PDF

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a simple HTML table with a dropdown filter, i want to export this table in PDF, and when i use the filter that changes the pdf too. If someone can help me that will be good :)

Data table: https://jsfiddle.net/hk8mvyda/

```
<SCRIPT language="Javascript">

function filterText()
{  

        var rex = new RegExp($('#Position').val());
        if(rex =="/All/"){clearFiltre()}else{
            $('.content').hide();
            $('.content').filter(function() {
            return rex.test($(this).text());
            }).show();

    }
    }
    function clearFiltre()
    {
        $('.Position').val('');
        $('.content').show();
    }
</script>
```

PS: Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

The filter uses javascript. If you want to be able to render the html to a PDF it will need to be something PHP can access. Since javascript does the change on the clients browser, PHP can not access it unless you use a Http request to get the html.

Use `file_get_contents(url)` to query the url and allow for a url variable to auto select the content of the dropdown. This way PHP can obtain the rendered HTML after the javascript has done what it needs to do .

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Answer (score 0):

Check this both jquery plugin example it maybehelpful to you

https://w3lessons.info/2015/07/13/export-html-table-to-excel-csv-json-pdf-png-using-jquery/

https://www.phpflow.com/php/export-html-table-data-to-excel-csv-png-and-pdf-using-jquery-plugin/